# Check if an NSString is an html string?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am creating an application that should display a list of strings, the string is returned from the server and can be  either an html or not.
I am currently setting the text inside a UILabel. to do that i am using the below

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedTitleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[title dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
cell.label.attributedText =attributedTitleString;
```

When the text is an html, everything work perfectly since the font and alignments are returned inside the html. The issue is occurring when the text is a normal text. The font, text alignment, text size and others are not being respected anymore.

So how can I check if the text is an html string or not?
I will be using the following in case of normal text:

```
cell.label.text =title;
```

I have tried to search on forums but still didn't get any answer for my issue.

Comment: What do you mean that the font pp. is not respected anymore? If it is plain text, there are no such attributes.

Comment: I mean when creating the label, i am setting the font to 20 for ex and settextalignment center. However when I set cell.label.attributedText =attributedTitleString (from a plain text) , the font is so small and aligned left

Comment: I think it's not possible. You can only check if your html string contain html tag. (With regex for example)

Comment: What happens if you (re-)set the attributes after assigning the plain text?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad  
I don't want to always set the font after setting the attribute text in case of html text because this will override the font returned from the html

Comment: Oh, I assumed that the html settings will be respected, if there are attributes.

Comment: Could to the trick: `if([[title dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] length] == [[attributedTitleString string] length]){//normal text}else{//html}`?

Comment: @Larme still not working (( i also tried if([title length] == ...) but not working in all cases

Comment: `[title length]` is better, since we want a `NSString` length, not a `NSData` one. Sorry for my mistake. Do you have an example case where it's not working?

Comment: I am receiving a text where the text is displaying "Your will.   Stay"  and the attribute is displaying "Your will. Stay"  . The difference of length is 3 and i can't know why the text is adding some tabs and space.(or maybe why the attribute is removing them)

Comment: With `NSString *title = @"Your will. Stay";` I got 15 at length for `attributedTitleString` and `title`.

Comment: @Larme, the string contains a tab and 2 spaces after the point, these does not exist in the attributedTitleString. I can't figure how they disappear in the attributedTitleString.

Comment: @Pipiks can you please help me how could I do that using regex?

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine, you need to put:

`cell.label. attributedText = title;` incase of normal text too.

As It is working fine. Run the below code.

**//If HTML Text**

```
NSString *htmlstr = `@"This is <font color='red'>simple</font>"`;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedTitleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

textField.attributedText =attributedTitleString;

textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"vardana" size:20.0];
```

**//If Normal text.**

```
NSString *normalStr = @"This is Renuka";

NSMutableAttributedString *NorAttributedTitleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[normalStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

textField.attributedText = NorAttributedTitleString;

textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"vardana" size:20.0];
```

Comment: I don't want to always set the font after setting the attribute text in case of html text since this will override the font returned from the html

Comment: I am not getting you, you want to change font of normal text only ?

Comment: exactly only for normal text , because the font is set automatically inside the HTML  in case the string is an html one

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your string contains html tag :

// iOS8 +

```
NSString *string = @"<TAG>bla bla bla html</TAG>";

if ([string containsString:@"<TAG"]) {
    NSLog(@"html string");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no html string");
}
```

// iOS7 +

```
NSString *string = @"<TAG>bla bla bla html</TAG>";

if ([string rangeOfString:@"<TAG"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"html string");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no html string");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the syntax and structure of HTML and XML is quite similar, you can utilize `XMLDocument` to check whether a given data object is HTML or plain text.

So data is from the type `Data` and is returned by an `URLSession` dataTask.

```
// Default to plain text
var options : [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.plain]

// This will succeed for HTML, but not for plain text                
if let _ = try? XMLDocument(data: data, options: []) {
     options[.documentType] = NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
}

guard let string = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else { return }
```

---

**Update**

The above method works *sort of*. I had trouble with some HTML not creating an XML document. For the moment I have a different solution, that I don't really like. 
As the symptom is that we get only one line back in the attributed string, simply check for that and create a new attributed string if there is only one line.

```
var options : [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]

guard var string = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else { return }

if string.string.split(separator: "\n").count == 1 {
    options[.documentType] = NSAttributedString.DocumentType.plain
    guard let tempString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else { return }
    string = tempString
}
```